# Struggling with adding new Gmail EventReservation schema Tags to emails

Tags: email, gmail

I am trying to test the new EventReservation Schema that Gmail offers to transaction confirmation emails sent from my site. I have followed all the steps recommendend on the site (https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/event-reservation).
I also used the Structured data markup helper (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/?email=true) to generate the Tags. using the script.google.com site i wrote a test to send the same confirmation emails but NO DICE!! Would anyone be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

How is your test failing? Are you expecting an inbox action button and not seeing it? Or are you expecting Google Now to generate a reminder card?

The Event Registration schema does not give the recipient an action button in the inbox. It should however be used by Google Now to generate a reminder card which will remind the recipient of the date/time of the event.

> Google Now will remind the user on the day of the event. The user will
>   receive a time to leave reminder (based on traffic etc).
>   - [Basic Event Reminder](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket)

When using the [RSVP Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/rsvp-action) schema it should cause an action button to be displayed in the inbox that shows a dialog for the recipient to respond with a yes/no/maybe in regard to if they will attend the event.

In either case there are currently (at the time of this writing) a few gotchas in regard to using these schemas.

The first thing you need to know is that you must [register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google) in order to be whitelisted to use these inbox actions in Gmail. Without registering and being whitelisted all you can do is send emails to yourself (your own Gmail account) in order to [test](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial) these schemas out. If your trying to send to someone else's Gmail account it will not work.

Many of these schemas are only in API Preview mode for now.

As of July 11, 2013 the RSVP Action is only enabled for emails sent by Google Calendar.

You can follow updates relating to the inbox actions on the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/release-notes) page.